# ASP domain and files

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic

I have no idea about asp, but I had to do some modifications in a web site, an easy modification. So I downloaded all files from server and I did all the modifications in Visual Studio 2013. Then I tested each page in the local host and it was perfect.
When I uploaded the files, I created a folder called "development", to tested it before I changed in the real site, so, my real site is for example "www.realsite.com" and my new folder is inside, with all the file, so I write in my url "www.realsite.com/development" and it shows the page, but not the one I had modified, but the real site. I want to know if there is a config file to change the path of the development site to see the changes I make and not the real site, because if I click in the development site a menu, it sends me to the page in the real site.
I hope you can help me with this,
Thank you!
PS: Do you know what is the meaning of "~/" in for example : src="~/folder/folder/xxxx.xx"

Comment: You've tagged this with both Classic ASP and ASP.net - which is it? If you have files with the extension "asp" then it's classic, if you have files with the extension "aspx" then it's .net

Comment: sorry, I didn't know that, I'm new in asp, and I hope I learn more about this. My file extensions are aspx

Comment: Perhaps your first step should be to [learn the difference](http://www.dotnetspider.com/tutorials/AspNet-Tutorial-26.aspx) between them.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the URLs in the project are using absolute paths, all pointing to the root. If they were using relative paths, moving the project to a folder and running it from there would work just file.

The difference:

`<a href="/page2.asp">...</a>` <-- absolute, note the leading slash

`<a href="page2.asp">...</a>` <-- relative, no leading slash

Comment: ok, but tht's not only the problem, because when I write in the url "www.realsite.com/development" is really showing me "www.realsite.com", not the new files I uploaded, always is pointing at "www.realsite.com"

Answer (score 0):

Well, it depends on what kind of changes you are referring to, what kind of ASP.net site (or application).

The `~/` in ASP.Net means "path from *application root*". A subfolder (the new folder  you created) in an existing application is just that, a folder. It is not "another application root". So if the existing code refers to "its root", e.g. where it uses `~/`, it's probably not what you would expect..

Again, not enough info, but if you experience more unexpected behavior, it will probably be because of this (application scope).

Ref: [ASP.NET Web Project Paths](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178116.aspx)

> ASP.NET includes the Web application root operator (~), which you can use when specifying a path in server controls. ASP.NET resolves the ~ operator to the root of the current application.

Hth...